# How to get output in sql two rates into two column in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help on this. Sometimes my title maybe wrong. Actually i'm unable to explain the problem in word. See below images. Image 1 is db table structure. Image 2 is what I expect result.

[image: Table structure]

[image: Expect result]

I used mentioned query and got result as below image. Also I need to remove 'NULL's and same URGENT_LEVEL values in one row. How i do that? Using ms-sql server.

select TRACKING_NUMBER,URGENT_LEVEL,
case when FROM_KM = '0' then Charge end as 'Under1km' ,
case when FROM_KM='1'  then Charge end as '1-100KM'

from my_table
where TRACKING_NUMBER = 'TEST001'

[After query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0N6Q.png)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: @DataDynamic . . . I added a database tag based on your comment below.  Please tag your questions with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select tracking_number, urgent_level,
       sum(case when to_km - from_km <= 1 then charge else 0 end) as charge_under_1,
       sum(case when to_km - from_km > 1 and to_km - from_km <= 100 then charge else 0 end) as charge_1_100 
from t
group by tracking_number, urgent_level;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database you are using, but you need to use group by clause, and something similar to case expression (in oracle) as below :

```sql
select TRACKING_NUMBER
, URGENT_LEVEL
, max(case when FROM_KM = 0 and TO_KM = 1 then CHARGE end) as "UNDER 1KM"
, max(case when FROM_KM = 1 and TO_KM = 100 then CHARGE end) as "1-100KM"
from your_table
where TRACKING_NUMBER = 'TEST001'
group by TRACKING_NUMBER, URGENT_LEVEL
order by "UNDER 1KM"
;
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using MS SQL 2008. Can you tell, what is the 'to_char' mean? is it data type converting?

Comment: Yes, it is data type converting. I just wanted to format the output numbers to "999.99" format. But, my solution also works without to_char function. I am going to remove to_char function.